# Finding a mimikatz file on a compromised host?

Tags: mimikatz, ioc

So I am currently struggling with a cyber security lab, and after searching various online sources and reading documentation I can't find a solution. The 2 tasks are as follows:

1. "The attacker has deployed the Mimikatz tool to attempt to
   capture plaintext passwords. What is the filename of the Mimikatz
   executable on disk?"
2. "The attacker has deployed a keylogger
   and has captured credentials for the webmail system for user Alan
   Jones (Alan Jones). What is the full path of the log file on disk?"

I am not quite sure how to find the tool, I think i could use regedt32 or powershell from what I have read.

Does anyone have experience in dealing with this/ a suggestion on how to find a specific file? (its not called mimikatz dont worry i already checked)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The attacker has deployed a keylogger...What is the full path of the log file on disk" There are too many different keyloggers to be able to answer this question. For the first question it should be easy to download the tool and extract it to see what the filename is.

Comment: @user the keylogger is called mimikatz as mentioned in question 1

Comment: mimikatz is not a keylogger

Comment: The entire point of the exercise is to figure out *how* to get these answers. Not to look up standard answers online. We can't help you without also being able to investigate the machine.

Comment: @schroeder♦ wanna come over to see the machine then? i got pizza